# Cloudfront bucket policy for video on demand

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, bucket

I am creating a video on demand platform similar to netflix. I want the users that have purchased the subscription to view my videos to be able to watch them (not download them). I also do not want the users to be able to copy the source of the video url, and access it through a new tab (this is working for now, it says access denied).

So what I have done for now is this, I have copied the official code from amazon's documentation, which allegedly only allows the content (in my case the video) to be played on the website that I specify. This is the policy:

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1408118342443",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1408118336209",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "aws:Referer": [
                    "https://mywebsite/*",
                    "https://mywebsite/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

So what hapenned was, I was not able to play the video on my site and I was not able to access the video by direct URL. I have tried selecting the video file, and allowing "Read object" for public access, but that only made my video be direcctly accessable by URL, which I don't want.

My "Block public access" permissions are all currently off, because if they are On I cannot edit the bucket policy (it says "Access denied" when I hit save).

My question is, how do I protect my video content from bandwith theft? I don't want a person to buy my membership, then send the direct video link to his friends so everyone can see. Allegedly to amazon this is possible, but what seems to be the problem?

Also I am planning to use Cloudfront after I solve this issue, so hopefully that won't interfere.

Comment: One possible solution could be the CloudFront signed cookies. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html

Comment: The condition bucket policy seems more cost efficient, because people can still steal the cookie signed link and give it to someone else.